# How can I get JNI file from decompiled apk

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I've decompiled apk file and found that `native` method is used. However I can't find JNI related file like c/c++ file.(can't find body of native method)

How can I find the body of native method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Native code can be found in the `libs` directory. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028407/809866) SO answer for more information:

> All of the native code for an app is stored in the libs/ directory in
>   the root of the apk. It's compiled ARM or x86 code, or both. You can
>   find it in libs/architecture_type/lib_name.so. You can dissemble the
>   code with objdump or gdb. Decompiling is a much harder task, but you
>   can find some software that might work for you.